# Optimised way to store large key value kind of data

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, nosql

I am working on a database that has a table user having columns user_id and user_service_id. My application needs to fetch all the users whose user_service_id is a particular value. Normally I would add an index to the user_service_id column and run a query like this :
`select user_id from user where user_service_id = 2;`

Since the cardinality of the column user_service_id is very less than around 3-4 and the table has around 10M entries, the query will end up scanning almost the entire table.
I was wondering what is the recommendation for such usecases. Also, would it make more sense to move the data to another nosql datastore as this doesn't seem to be an efficient usecase for MySQL or any SQL datastore? Tried to search this but couldn't find any recommendations here. Can someone please help or provide the necessary references?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query will retrieve approximately 2.5 million values on average.  How do you expect that to be efficient?

Comment: yeah right, that's why wanted to know what is the recommendation around storing & fetching such kind of data.  @GilbertLeBlanc

Comment: How often would this list change? Have you considered keeping the list in memory via a cache, like redis? Also, have you tested performance with a covering index (with user_service_id, user_id order of columns)?

Comment: It would probably be faster to SELECT the entire table and use the application code to select the user service ID.

Comment: this list is very dynamic. The frequency of change is high. @Shadow

Answer (score 0):

That query needs this index, which is both "composite" and "covering":

```
INDEX(user_service_id, user_id)   -- in this order
```

But what will you do with the millions of rows that you get?  Sounds like it will choke the client, whether it comes fast or slow.

See my [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

"very dynamic" -- Not a problem.

"cache" -- the dynamic nature defeats caching.

"cardinality" -- not important, except to point out that there will be millions of rows.

"millions of rows" -- that takes time to deliver to the client.  The number of rows delivered is the biggest factor in cost.

"select entire table, then filter in client" -- That will be even slower!  (See "millions of rows".)